# Excel - Updating an Absolute Reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to use both absolute and relative references in the same formula that will span both rows AND columns.  I'd like to be able to fill down and the keep my column header referenced, but if I fill across I want it to grab the new column header but keep the row I'm on the same.  My end goal with this formula is to have a matrix, so if Joe Smith is an approver for for a certain work flow, it will show an 'x' where is his name and that approval meet.

Example:
Current formula `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE($B$2,A3),'All Approvals'!$D$2:$D$175,1,FALSE)),"","x")`

If I fill down it will update `A3` to `A4` but If move to the right it will keep `A3` and update `$B$2` to `$C$2`

I do understand that, by definition, the absolute reference is doing absolutely what it should *wink wink*.  So if the answer is to update the absolute in each new column, that's fine.  But any thoughts on this would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to update the new headers across columns.

Try:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(B$2,A3),'All Approvals'!$D$2:$D$175,1,FALSE)),"","x")
```

This will still preserve the 2nd row (which I'm assuming is your header row).

Comment: Updated my concatenate to `(B$2,$A3)` per your recommendation and it works great.  Thank you