# Excel Formula Increment Selected Values

Tags: excel, formula, increment

I am trying to use excel to auto increment a formula each when I drag it down to additional rows, however it does not seem to be working. The formula I have checks to see if a value falls between certain numbers. For example Cell H2 falls in between the values of C7 and D7.

```
=IF(AND(H2<C7,H2>D7),"Yes", "No")
```

When I drag the formula down to the next row it will turn into:

```
=IF(AND(H3<C8,H3>D8),"Yes", "No")
```

It should be:

```
=IF(AND(H2<C8,H2>D8),"Yes", "No")
```

The problem is I have about 2000 entries that need this. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Absolute references

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue. All I needed was a push in the right direction. @RobinGertenbach

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel - Updating an Absolute Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842342/excel-updating-an-absolute-reference)

Answer (score 0):

You need to absolutely reference the `H2`, here - 
`=IF(AND($H$2<C7,$H$2>D7),"Yes", "No")`

Comment: Did you mean `=IF(AND($H$2<C7,$H$2>D7),"Yes", "No")`? It happens :)

Comment: @Boris It's morning time here!